# scrollTo(y,x,animated ) is deprecated in react-native using ScrollView

Tags: react-native

Hai while i am using ScrollView in react-native, I got some warning messages like scrollTo(y,x,animated) is deprecated, Below is the screenShot images for both android and IOS.

[image]

can you any one give me suggestions that how to solve this type of warnings i got this while using react-native version:0.21. Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 9):

They changed the syntax, now `scrollTo` gets only one `Object` argument. Use it like this now:

```
 scrollView.scrollTo({ y: newY, animated: true });
```